# Any way other than setTimeout to force a browser repaint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, repaint

I'm using (and contributing to) a jQuery table sorting plugin that includes an event for extra processing before the table is sorted. Originally the browser didn't do a repaint before sorting, so I added a setTimeout call to the plugin code that should force a repaint. So the code is now like this:

```
$table.trigger("beforetablesort", {column: th_index, direction: sort_dir});

setTimeout(function() {
  // do the hard work
}, 10);
```

My `beforetablesort` callback is like this:

```
table.bind('beforetablesort', function (event, data) {
  $("table").css({opacity: 0.5});
});
```

The above all works fine. However, if I use `addClass` instead of inline styles, the changes from that class do not show until the table is fully sorted:

```
table.bind('beforetablesort', function (event, data) {
  $("table").addClass('disabled');
});
```

If I increase the timeout to over 500ms, the opacity does change. It seems like it takes a tiny bit longer for a class change to be visible as opposed to an inline style change. But by the time the browser is ready to repaint it's already doing the table sorting.

Is there a way to force the repaint earlier? Or wait until the repaint for the table sorting code to run? Increasing the timeout arbitrarily doesn't seem like a good solution as it forces all tables to take at least half a second to sort. (Full code of the plugin is [here on Github](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin) if it helps.)

Comment: You're not "forcing" a browser repaint so much as _allowing_ a repaint.

Comment: Reading some computed property will wait for reflow. Hopefully it will ensure a repaint as well.

Comment: Maybe you should start by making your plugin less computationally expensive. There seem to be lots of things that'll individually run much faster with very small changes. Not that it'll solve this issue, but perhaps it'll make it less relevant.

Comment: @thesystem I didn't write it but I have been contributing to it. Feel free to contribute yourself or create an issue on Github suggesting some of the "very small changes", we'd love to hear them.

Comment: I'll leave that up to you, but much of it is centered around unnecessary use of jQuery, which always slows things down. But taking a closer look at the code, it seems the code is using a very expensive `sort_map` in order to sort an array of the column cells, analyse the indices to create an array of indices representing the new order, and then apply that new order to the rows. Why not just make an array of the rows, sort that array using the proper cell index, and then append the result? There are other code issues too, but I think this seems to be the greatest.

Comment: @JanDvorak that seems to work pretty well. Feel free to post as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Jan Dvorak above works.

> Reading some computed property will wait for reflow. Hopefully it will ensure a repaint as well.

I just added the line `$table.css("display");` and the browser repaints the table before the sorting starts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already considered using $.deferred() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/.
The code in timeout should go in the callback handler when deferred object is resolved

Comment: What does that do differently to a `setTimeout` call?